# not displayed navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, segue, navigationbar

I have two controllers, the first (UITableViewController) and second (UIViewController), in both there UINavigationBar. When I'm in the second controller, I'm using the UIBarButtonItem I want to go back to the first controller while maintaining data. The data is stored and the transition is obtained, but does not load UINavigationBar in the first controller. Help me please.

```
@IBAction func buttonDone(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if countElements(textView.text) > 0 {
        saveText()
        toBackFirst()

    }
}

func toBackFirst() {
    let firstViewController:FirstTableViewController = FirstTableViewController()
    self.presentViewController(firstViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using presentViewController. You need to push it to the navigationStack using push.

Try this:

```
func toBackFirst() {
    let firstViewController:FirstTableViewController = FirstTableViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(firstViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: It works, but the transition button that was added to the Storyboard is not displayed.

Comment: oh you're using storyboards. In that case you need to look up how to perform a segue programatically. I never use storyboards, so I can't help you with a concrete code example. But just googling "swift segue programatically" should get you the answers you're looking for.